# REACTJS: How can I call the setter inside a function from a function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My boss wants me to do the following: In the *main* function there is a constant state '*error*' and a setter of the error. I want to call the setter '*setError*' from the function called *update*.

```
function update(index: number, value: string, group: number[]) {
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(value))) {
        group[i] = Number(value);

        call here to setter and set error = false
    }
    else {
        call here to setter and set error = true
    }
}

function main(props: { info: any; }) {
    const [error, setError] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
    (...)
}
```

Comment: where exactly is this `update` function being used ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass setter as argument to update function, something like this:

```
function update(index: number, value: string, group: number[], setError: someType) {
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(value))) {
        group[i] = Number(value);

        setError(false)
    }
    else {
        setError(true)
    }
}
```

And then pass the setter when you call update funtion:

```
update(index, value, group, setError) // Pass the state setter here
```